# scan function to read in space prefixed strings

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a macro wherein my paramter has multiple values and a few of those are prefxed with space. I want to be able to read in the strings along with the space, but space being the default delimiter is causing issues.

```
`%macro ab(where_p=);
 data want;
 set have;
 %DO I =1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&WHERE_P));
 %IF %LENGTH(&WHERE_P) > 0 %THEN %DO;
 B_&I=%SCAN(%STR(&WHERE_P),&I);
 %end;
 %end;
 run;
 %mend;
 %ab(WHERE_P=" ATF" " TRUST");`
```

Here it is not able to read in values as is, it reads a space as one string then ATF as next and then space again and TRUST as next. Wherein, it should read ' ATF' as one string and 'TRUST'as second.
Can someone help read in such data using scan function.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try override default delimeter? You can add it as second param in countw function. Also, what do you wanna to do? May be your task will be easier to do with arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the functionality of the %SCAN() function to handle this.  If the data includes the delimiter then the values need to be quoted.

```
%let WHERE_P=" ATF" " TRUST";
%let word1 = %scan(&where_p,1,%str( ),q);
```

So your loop should look like:

```
%IF %LENGTH(&WHERE_P) %THEN %DO I =1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&WHERE_P,%str( ),q));
   B_&I=%SCAN(&where_p,&I,%str( ),q);
%end;
...
%ab(WHERE_P=" ATF" " TRUST");`
```

Or you could use a different delimiter that does NOT appear in the data.  If you want to pass in leading spaces without actual quotes then you need to use macro quoting.

```
%IF %LENGTH(&WHERE_P) %THEN %DO I =1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&WHERE_P,|));
   B_&I=%sysfunc(quote(%qSCAN(&where_p,&I,|)));
%end;
...
%ab(WHERE_P=%str( ATF| TRUST));
```

Comment: This worked well and that too without having to add arrays , etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
%macro ab(where_p=);
  %let array_size = %EVAL(%SYSFUNC(COUNTC(&WHERE_P, '"'))/2);
  data want;
    set have;
    array B_(&array_size) $20 (&where_p);
  run;
%mend;
%ab(WHERE_P=" ATF" " TRUST" );
```

You first find the number of items which is number of quotes divided by 2.
Then create an array of that size and assign values using &WHERE_P directly.

If you want to allow strings in WHERE_P longer than 20 chars, you need to change the length in the array line.